# Android Studio redeclaration error when compiling release while having Kotlin Poet generated classes

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, kotlinpoet, redeclaration

My app uses Kotlin Poet to generate some classes at compile time. These classes are generated in `app/build/generated/source/kaptKotlin [main]` and there in two subfolders `debug."packagename"` and `release [main]/"packagename"`, depending on if I compile for debug or release.

When I compile for debug and then for release both subfolders will be present and thus resulting in a compiler error *Redeclaration: classname*.

I can work around that by deleting the opposite subfolder before I compile, i.e. deleting the debug subfolder when I compile for release and vice versa.

Still this is annoying and I am wondering if there are some settings I could apply to avoid this.